# pass an event to all related views in android

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to change multiple `TextView` text sizes all at once? Also they may or may not be in single `ViewGroup`. I was hoping of doing by creating some kind of trigger/event that would act like pub/sub but got no ideas. Any Possibility?

Comment: Take a look at Event Bus for android.It is new concept and you can use it for your current requirement.

Comment: Looks interesting, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a class which you register the TextViews with.  Then have a method which goes through all the registered TextViews and sets the font size.  Somethings like:

```
public class TextViewTextSizer {

    private List<TextView> textViews;

    public TextViewTextSizer() {

        textViews = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void registerTextView(TextView textView) {

        textViews.add(textView);
    }

    public void setTextSize(float size) {

        for (TextView textView : textViews) {
            textView.setTextSize(size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did had that in mind, but holding textviews list might not be that efficient what I am looking for.